# Please help me access nested array

Tags: arrays, ruby, padrino

I have an array that is called from an API. The data returned is like so (tidied up for display purposes).

```
[
    {
        "MessageThreadID": 30044,
        "CustomerID": 433,
        "MessageType": 1,
        "Subject": "What is my account balance?",
        "OpenDate": "2015-12-21T10:36:00",
        "Closed": false,
        "ClosedDate": null,
        "Messages": [
            {
                "IBMessageID": 30076,
                "MessageThreadID": 30044,
                "MessageText": "What is my account balance?",
                "FromCustomer": true,
                "UserID": null,
                "Date": "2015-12-21T10:36:00"
            },
            {
                "IBMessageID": 30077,
                "MessageThreadID": 30044,
                "MessageText": "Â£1230.00",
                "FromCustomer": false,
                "UserID": 1,
                "Date": "2015-12-21T10:36:00"
            },
            {
                "IBMessageID": 30078,
                "MessageThreadID": 30044,
                "MessageText": "Thanks you",
                "FromCustomer": true,
                "UserID": null,
                "Date": "2015-12-21T10:37:00"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

From this I use the following in my helpers to make the call to the API and return this data.

```
def contact_messages_threads(customer_id)

  customer_id = @customer.id
  response = get_call('/Messages/GetOpenedMessages/' + customer_id.to_s)
  response = JSON.parse(response.body)

  @openmessagethreads = {}
  @openmessagethreads = response.map do |openmessagethread|
    Contact.new(openmessagethread) 
  end

  return @openmessagethreads

end
```

My contact model is as below where the different sections are defined.

```
class Contact
  attr_accessor :message_customer_ID, :message_type, :message_subject, :message_source, :message_thread_ID, :messages, :messages_test, :message_text, :from_customer, 
  :message_user_id, :message_date, :openmessagethreads
  attr_reader :messages

  def initialize(options)

    @message_customer_ID        = options['CustomerID'].to_s 
    @message_type               = options['MessageType'].to_s 
    @message_subject            = options['Subject'].to_s 
    @message_source             = options['Closed'].to_s 
    @message_thread_ID          = options['MessageThreadID'].to_s 
    @messages                   = options['Messages']
    @messages_test              = options['Messages']['IBMessageID'].to_s
    @message_text               = options['MessageText']
    @from_customer              = options['FromCustomer']
    @message_user_id            = options['UserID']
    @message_date               = options['OpenDate']
    @openmessagethreads = {}

  end

end
```

Finally in my view I call the data like so:

```
- contact_messages_threads(@customer.id).each do |openmessagethread|
  = openmessagethread.message_subject
```

From this I am able to quite easily call data such as IBMessageThreadID, CustomerID etc however I cannot access the Messages array and what is contained within. I have worked at this when i get a spare minute for the last two months and still havent been able to crack it. I think i may need to change my model, api call or possibly view but have been trying different variations I have found online but cant seem to crack it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Generally its a good idea to share minimal enough code that drives the point through - in other words, demonstrates the issue you are facing.  The down votes to your question is probably due to overwhelming amount of code, and lack of clarity on what is the issue you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the array, you need to use array index.

Instead of using

```
@messages_test              = options['Messages']['IBMessageID'].to_s
```

you need to use, to access to first element the array`options['Messages']` array, below code

```
@messages_test              = options['Messages'][0]['IBMessageID'].to_s
```

You can iterate the array, if you wish, by using

```
options['Messages'] each do |item|
    puts item["IBMessageID"]  # for illustration
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Did as you said however adding options['Messages'][0]['IBMessageID'].to_s to the model caused me problems. Took it out again and it works okay so leaving it out unless you have any reason to keep it in. Anyway it worked so thanks for the help. Cant believe it was so easy but the main point is it was explained in a straightforward manner.